# How to exit a console application without requiring enter

Tags: c#, console-application

What would be the best way to exit an application when a user types `x` without having to hit enter. The current code I am using is this:

```
Console.WriteLine("\nType x to exit > ");
string test = Console.ReadLine();
while (test != "x")
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nType x to exit > ");
    test = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This will make the user experience better.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Console.ReadKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3h8xffw) instead.

> Obtains the next character or function key pressed by the user. The pressed key is optionally displayed in the console window.

Answer (score 1):

`Console.ReadKey()` let you read a single key press. `Console.readLine()` is waiting for a line termination. Here's the doc for reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85.aspx

You can read the first character and then if it's not "x", read a line input (and prepend the first char received before).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nType x to exit > ");
}
while (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar != 'x');
```